# Как в symfony реализовать форму обратной связи

Tags: php, symfony

Как в **symfony** реализовать форму обратной связи , отправку номера телефона пользователя на почту , можно ли это сделать через консоль

```
php app/console
```

хотелось бы по подробнее с примерами так как я полный ноль в **symfony**
и как там все работает не имею представления - за исключением шаблонов **twig**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

На symfony3

Создание FormType для контактной формы

Следующий класс содержит ContactType, который будет использоваться для создания формы в контроллере позже.

```
<?php
// your-path-to-types/ContactType.php

namespace myapplication\myBundle\Form;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\TextType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\TextareaType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\EmailType;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints\Email;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints\NotBlank;

class ContactType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('name', TextType::class, array('attr' => array('placeholder' => 'Your name'),
                'constraints' => array(
                    new NotBlank(array("message" => "Please provide your name")),
                )
            ))
            ->add('subject', TextType::class, array('attr' => array('placeholder' => 'Subject'),
                'constraints' => array(
                    new NotBlank(array("message" => "Please give a Subject")),
                )
            ))
            ->add('email', EmailType::class, array('attr' => array('placeholder' => 'Your email address'),
                'constraints' => array(
                    new NotBlank(array("message" => "Please provide a valid email")),
                    new Email(array("message" => "Your email doesn't seems to be valid")),
                )
            ))
            ->add('message', TextareaType::class, array('attr' => array('placeholder' => 'Your message here'),
                'constraints' => array(
                    new NotBlank(array("message" => "Please provide a message here")),
                )
            ))
        ;
    }

    public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'error_bubbling' => true
        ));
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'contact_form';
    }
}
```

Создание представления в Twig

Теперь представление (в данном случае, которое будет отображаться через twig), должно быть базовым для проверки:

```
{# contact.html.twig #}

{{ form_start(form) }}

    <div>
        {{ form_widget(form.subject) }}
        {{ form_errors(form.subject) }}
    </div>
    <div>
        {{ form_widget(form.name) }}
        {{ form_errors(form.name) }}
    </div>
    <div>
        {{ form_widget(form.email) }}
        {{ form_errors(form.email) }}
    </div>
    <div>
        {{ form_widget(form.message) }}
        {{ form_errors(form.message) }}
    </div>

    {# Render CSRF token etc .#}
    <div style="display:none">
        {{ form_rest(form) }}
    </div>

    <input type="submit" value="Submit">

{{ form_end(form) }}
```

Создание контроллера

Теперь, самый важный момент, контроллер, который будет обрабатывать нашу форму.

Как обычно, ваше действие в контроллере должно уже иметь путь в файле routing.yml, и он нацелен на него:

```
myapplication_contact:
    path:     /contact
    defaults: { _controller: myBundle:Default:contact }
```

Наконец, наш контроллер (с контактным действием) должен выглядеть так:

```
<?php

namespace myapplication\myBundle\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;

class DefaultController extends Controller
{
    public function contactAction(Request $request)
    {
        // Create the form according to the FormType created previously.
        // And give the proper parameters
        $form = $this->createForm('myapplication\myBundle\Form\ContactType',null,array(
            // To set the action use $this->generateUrl('route_identifier')
            'action' => $this->generateUrl('myapplication_contact'),
            'method' => 'POST'
        ));

        if ($request->isMethod('POST')) {
            // Refill the fields in case the form is not valid.
            $form->handleRequest($request);

            if($form->isValid()){
                // Send mail
                if($this->sendEmail($form->getData())){

                    // Everything OK, redirect to wherever you want ! :

                    return $this->redirectToRoute('redirect_to_somewhere_now');
                }else{
                    // An error ocurred, handle
                    var_dump("Errooooor :(");
                }
            }
        }

        return $this->render('myBundle:Default:contact.html.twig', array(
            'form' => $form->createView()
        ));
    }

    private function sendEmail($data){
        $myappContactMail = 'mycontactmail@mymail.com';
        $myappContactPassword = 'yourmailpassword';

        // In this case we'll use the ZOHO mail services.
        // If your service is another, then read the following article to know which smpt code to use and which port
        // http://ourcodeworld.com/articles/read/14/swiftmailer-send-mails-from-php-easily-and-effortlessly
        $transport = \Swift_SmtpTransport::newInstance('smtp.zoho.com', 465,'ssl')
            ->setUsername($myappContactMail)
            ->setPassword($myappContactPassword);

        $mailer = \Swift_Mailer::newInstance($transport);

        $message = \Swift_Message::newInstance("Our Code World Contact Form ". $data["subject"])
        ->setFrom(array($myappContactMail => "Message by ".$data["name"]))
        ->setTo(array(
            $myappContactMail => $myappContactMail
        ))
        ->setBody($data["message"]."<br>ContactMail :".$data["email"]);

        return $mailer->send($message);
    }
}
```